# Decode simple API array Swift

Tags: swift, api, struct, decode

I am struggling to decode a specific object returned by an API, I can't figure out the correct `struct`.

What's wrong?

Here is the returned `API` `JSON`:

```
{
    "votes": [
     {
        "votesId": "1",
        "vote_nb": "6",
        "current_time": "0",
        "trend_up": "0",
        "trend_down": "0",
        "position_hold": "0",
        "position_buy": "0",
        "position_sell": "0"
    }]
}
```

And my code to `decode` and `fetch`:

```
struct VoteData : Codable {
    let votes : [Votes]
}

struct Votes : Codable {
    let vote_nb : String
}

func fetchData(completion: @escaping (VoteData?, Error?) -> Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "...")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil, error ?? APIError.unknownNetworkError)
            return
        }
        do {
            let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(VoteData.self, from: data); completion(result, nil)
            let vote_nb = result.votes.vote_nb // Value of type '[Votes]' has no member 'vote_nb'
            print("VOTE NUMBER: ", vote_nb)
        } catch let parseError {
            completion(nil, parseError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: *Hint:* `result.votes` is an *array,* it can have zero, one, or more elements.

Comment: `result.votes[0].vote_nb` :D

Answer (score 0):

First select a particular member of the array, then check that property of THE member.

Change this line:

```
let vote_nb = result.votes.vote_nb
```

For this:

```
let vote_nb = result.votes[0].vote_nb
```